# Split a file into multiple files based on a pattern and name the new files by the search pattern in Unix?

Tags: unix, grep

How can I split a file based on a search pattern and the new files that will be generated will have the file names as equal to the search pattern which was used to split the file.

Currently, I'm using the following command to split files.

```
awk '/^GROUP*/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' cdw_all_jobs_reduced3.txt
```

It generated files by the names as F1, F2 and so on. But I want the names of files to be equal to the search pattern line.

i.e. If in my original file I have the following:

```
GROUP1
xyz
pqr
GROUP2
abc
GROUP3
sdlsa
```

Then the new files should be split by the search pattern GROUP* & renamed as GROUP1, GROUP2 and GROUP3 containing their respective content.

In other words, how do I custom generate(rename) the names of the files that will be split based on the search pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/^GROUP[0-9]+$/{x=$0;next}{print > x;}' cdw_all_jobs_reduced3.txt
```

If you want the "filenames" remove next statement:

```
awk '/^GROUP[0-9]+$/{x=$0}{print > x;}' cdw_all_jobs_reduced3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I knew it had to be some shell variable which stored the search pattern. But couldn't guess it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to people that might have a large number of files that have to be generated. Your command will crash unless you close the previously generated file first, so the improved version of `Juan Diego Godoy`'s answer would be:

```
awk '/^GROUP[0-9]+$/{close(x);x=$0}{print > x;}' cdw_all_jobs_reduced3.txt
```