# Splitting files into multiple files based on some pattern and take some information

Tags: database, bash, awk, sh

I'm working with a lot of files with this structure:

```
BEGIN
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1393
PEPMASS=946.3980102539062
CHARGE=3.0+
USER03=
SEQ=DDDIAAL
TAXONOMY=9606
272.228 126847.000
273.252 33795.000
END

BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1383
PEPMASS=911.3920288085938
CHARGE=2.0+
USER03=
SEQ=QGKFEAAETLEEAAMR
TAXONOMY=9606
1394.637    71404.000
1411.668    122728.000
END

BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=2965
PEPMASS=946.3900146484375
CHARGE=3.0+
TAXONOMY=9606
1564.717    92354.000
1677.738    33865.000
END
```

This structure is repeated thousands of times but with different data inside. As you can see, between some begin-end, sometimes SEQ and USER03 are not there. This is because the protein is not identified ... And here comes my problem.

I would like to know how many proteins are identified and how many are unidentified. To do this I was trying this:

```
for i in $(ls *.txt ); do
    echo $i

    awk '/^BEGIN/{n++;w=1} n&&w{print > "./cache/out" n ".txt"} /^END/{w=0}' $i

done
```

I found this here ([Split a file into multiple files based on a pattern and name the new files by the search pattern in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991963/split-a-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-pattern-and-name-the-new-files-by-th))

And then use the outputs and classify them:

```
for i in $(ls cache/*.txt ); do
    echo $i

    if grep -q 'SEQ' $i; then
        mv $i ./archive_identified
    else
        mv $i ./archive_unidentified
    fi
done
```

After this, I'd like to take some data (Example: spectrum, USER03, SEQ, TAXONOMY) from classified files.

```
for I in $( ls archive_identified/*.txt ); do
    echo $i
    grep 'SEQ' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./sequences_ide.txt
    grep 'TAXONOMY' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./taxonomy_ide.txt
    grep 'USER' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- >> ./modifications_ide.txt
    grep 'TITLE' $i | sed 's/^.*\(spectrum.*\)/\1/g' | cut -d "=" -f2-  >> ./spectrum.txt

done

for i in $( ls archive_unidentified/*.txt ); do
    echo $i
    grep 'SEQ' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./sequences_unide.txt
    grep 'TAXONOMY' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./taxonomy_unide.txt
    grep 'USER' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- >> ./modifications_unide.txt
    grep 'TITLE' $i | sed 's/^.*\(spectrum.*\)/\1/g' | cut -d "=" -f2-  >> ./spectrum_unide.txt

done
```

The problem is that the first part of the script takes too much time due to the large size of the data (12-15gb.). Is there any way to do this easier?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `awk` to convert each record to a CSV of the column data: SEQ, TAXONOMY, USER, TITLE. Then use `grep` to split that file into two: those with and those without a SEQ. Then use `cut` to pull columns into separate files. Alternatively: just do it all in `awk`.

Comment: @bishop Could you give me some clue how I can do that? I never worked with csv files.

Comment: Doesn't have to a CSV: any ad-hoc format will do. The trick is to rotate your row-oriented records into a column-oriented format, because you're "working against the grain" with the source data format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all in one `awk` script.  `awk` can iterate through all rows (records) so you don't need an external loop.  For example, for the data file you provided

```
$ awk -v RS= '/\nSEQ/ {seq++;   print > "file_path_with_seq" NR ".txt"; next} 
                      {noseq++; print > "file_path_without_seq" NR ".txt"} 
                 END  {         print "with seq:", seq; 
                                print "without seq:", noseq}' file
```

will print

```
with seq: 2
without seq: 1
```

and produces the files

```
$ head file_path_with*

==> file_path_with_seq1.txt <==
BEGIN
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1393
PEPMASS=946.3980102539062
CHARGE=3.0+
USER03=
SEQ=DDDIAAL
TAXONOMY=9606
272.228 126847.000
273.252 33795.000
END

==> file_path_with_seq2.txt <==
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1383
PEPMASS=911.3920288085938
CHARGE=2.0+
USER03=
SEQ=QGKFEAAETLEEAAMR
TAXONOMY=9606
1394.637    71404.000
1411.668    122728.000
END

==> file_path_without_seq3.txt <==
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=2965
PEPMASS=946.3900146484375
CHARGE=3.0+
TAXONOMY=9606
1564.717    92354.000
1677.738    33865.000
END
```

Comment: My concern would be minimizing I/O, in general, as that with the 12GB source that's going to be a lot of overhead. +1

Comment: @karakfa Wow... Your answer is really top and works perfectly

Comment: As I've mentioned many times before, the result of not parenthesizing an expression the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior so some awks WILL fail with `print > "file_path_with_seq" NR ".txt"`. Just parenthesize it and it'll work in all awks and have slightly better readability: `print > ("file_path_with_seq" NR ".txt")`. With awks other than GNU awk you'll have to close previous files as you go too so you'd really be better off with `close(seqOut); seqOut="file_path_with_seq" NR ".txt"; print > seqOut` for 100% portability to all awks.

Comment: @karakfa When I run your code I've got the result of each file that I analyze. Is it possible to have the total count of files that have / doesn't have SEQ?

Example: Using you script `file1 : with_seq 1, without_seq 2 / file2: with_seq 3, without_seq 1`. 
With what I want: `with_seq_total: 4 , without_seq_total: 3 `

Comment: you can run the script will all files at once like `awk ... file1 file2 file3 ...`, so the counts will only be printed at the end as the overall sum.