# Splitting files based on some pattern and the information inside the chunk

Tags: python, bash, perl

I'm working with a lot of files with this structure:

```
BEGIN
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1393
PEPMASS=946.3980102539062
CHARGE=3.0+
USER03=
SEQ=DDDIAAL
TAXONOMY=9606
272.228 126847.000
273.252 33795.000
END
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=1383
PEPMASS=911.3920288085938
CHARGE=2.0+
USER03=
SEQ=QGKFEAAETLEEAAMR
TAXONOMY=9606
1394.637    71404.000
1411.668    122728.000
END
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=id=PRD000012;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1645.xml;spectrum=2965
PEPMASS=946.3900146484375
CHARGE=3.0+
TAXONOMY=9606
1564.717    92354.000
1677.738    33865.000
END
```

This structure is repeated thousands of times but with different data inside. As you can see, between some begin-end, sometimes SEQ and USER03 are not there. This is because the protein is not identified ... And here comes my problem.

I would like to know how many proteins are identified and how many are unidentified. To do this I decided to use bash due to it is easier to manage files with it.

```
for i in $(ls *.txt ); do
    echo $i

    awk '/^BEGIN/{n++;w=1} n&&w{print > "./cache/out" n ".txt"} /^END/{w=0}' $i

done
```

I found this here ([Split a file into multiple files based on a pattern and name the new files by the search pattern in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991963/split-a-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-pattern-and-name-the-new-files-by-th))

And then use the outputs and classify them:

```
for i in $(ls cache/*.txt ); do
    echo $i

    if grep -q 'SEQ' $i; then
        mv $i ./archive_identified
    else
        mv $i ./archive_unidentified
    fi
done
```

After this, I'd like to take some data (Example: spectrum, USER03, SEQ, TAXONOMY) from classified files.

```
for i in $( ls archive_identified/*.txt ); do
    echo $i
    grep 'SEQ' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./sequences_ide.txt
    grep 'TAXONOMY' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./taxonomy_ide.txt
    grep 'USER' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- >> ./modifications_ide.txt
    grep 'TITLE' $i | sed 's/^.*\(spectrum.*\)/\1/g' | cut -d "=" -f2-  >> ./spectrum.txt

done

for i in $( ls archive_unidentified/*.txt ); do
    echo $i
    grep 'TAXONOMY' $i | cut -d "=" -f2- | tr ',' '\n' >> ./taxonomy_unide.txt
    grep 'TITLE' $i | sed 's/^.*\(spectrum.*\)/\1/g' | cut -d "=" -f2-  >> ./spectrum_unide.txt

done
```

The problem is that the first part of the script takes too much time (I ran the script 7 days ago in a LSF and it still keeps running)  due to the large size of the data (12-15gb each file) and generate thousand of files . Is there any way to do this in Python or Perl?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need from this data?  How many of each (of `USER03` and `SEQ`) is missing, or together?  What else?  You didn't specify what you need.

Comment: Do you actually need to separate all the individual `BEGIN`,`END` blocks out into individual files, because you could easily generate all the answers you seem to need in a single pass with `awk` or `Perl`?

Comment: @zdim As I said, there are chunks of text that have USER03 and SEQ and other pieces of text without them. Basically what I want is to separate those pieces to be able to classify them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, but using the condition if SEQ exists in the chunk of test or not.

Comment: 'USER03=',  is this always empty?

Comment: **Why** do you need separate files? There is no reason to generate them in order to get any results you have indicated above.

Comment: @宏杰李 Sometimes yes but sometimes no. Anyway, I could use just SEQ= to classify them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well... After that I use an R script to do a Quality Control. For example: How many SEQ do i have, frequency table of the Taxonomy, how many modifications etc...

Comment: It's quite easy in perl, but what are you looking to get out? You can certainly set `$/` to `END` and iterate record by record in perl, which works very nicely. But otherwise, this looks like an `XY problem` - I would suggest you backtrack and explain the goal.

Comment: @Sobrique I'd like to have a file with only chunks that have SEQ and another file with chunks of text that do not have SEQ.

Comment: So two files? That's _really_ easy.

Comment: @enrique Do you want just filenames or the content of the filenames in two different files whether grep or not?

Comment: And that is the sole criterion?  Can `SEQ=` have nothing and how does that count, or can it only happen that the `SEQ` line is missing altogether?  What about those `USER03` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment: "I'd like to have a file with only chunks that have SEQ and another file with chunks of text that do not have SEQ"

In Perl, I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $has_seq, '>', 'SEQ' ) or die $!;
open ( my $no_seq, '>', 'NO_SEQ' ) or die $!;
my $seq_count = 0;
my $no_seq_count = 0;

local $/ = 'END'; 

#iterate stdin or files specified on command line, just like sed/grep
while ( <> ) {
    #check if this chunk contains the word 'SEQ'.
    #regex match, so it'll match this text anywhere. 
    #maybe need to tighen up to ^SEQ= or similar? 
    if ( m/SEQ/ ) { 
        #choose output filehandle
        $seq_count++;
        select $has_seq;
    }
    else { 
       $no_seq_count++;
       select $no_seq;
    }
    #print current block to selected filehandle. 
    print;
}

select \*STDOUT; 
print "SEQ: $seq_count\n"; 
print "No SEQ: $no_seq_count\n";
```

This'll create two files (called creatively "SEQ" and "NO_SEQ") and split the results from your source.

Comment: I suspect OP may not realise he can avoid the `for` loop he currently has and just use `./YourScript *.txt`